# Can I use DriveApp searchFiles function to look for grandparent rather than parent folders?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am still new to using the `DriveApp.searchFiles()` function, and I am wondering if instead of looking for parents, I can zoom out one and have it confined to grandparents instead of the just the immediate superior folder. Here is my part of the script:

```js
var filesource = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '" + cellvenue + "' and title contains '" + cellperiod + "' and parents in '{parent folder ID}'");
if(filesource.hasNext() === true){
  while(filesource.hasNext()){
    var File = filesource.next();
    var ID = File.getId(); 
  }
}
```

what I would like is for the search to iterate through the grandparent folder, all of the subfolders of that, and all of the files of those respective subfolders. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am still new to the drive api functionality of scripts. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: The method you are using `DriveApp.searchFiles()` returns a file iterator.Perhaps you are looking to search for all files that match a query **within** a given or known folder??

Comment: Yes correct. I just want it to search through all sub-folders of a particular folder for the file that matches a particular parameter and then cycle through that same procedure for the i+ function.

Comment: Actually I just realized, I can use the exact same function but with search folder, and then build that in as a variable into the search files, so I think i got it. I will update if I need more help, thank you guys for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DriveApp.searchFiles()` method returns **all the files in the user's Drive that match the query**. The object returned by the method is a **`FileIterator`**. So you iterate through it to get each **`File`** object with it's properties. (eg. parents, id, name, etc...)

Also in your code you are nesting a `while` within an `if` statement, but the `while` already checks if the condition is true. You can avoid the extra lines by doing something like the following:

```js
var files_matching_query = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '" + cellvenue + "' and title contains '" + cellperiod + "' and parents in '{parent folder ID}'");

// While the iterator "files_matching_query" has next file
while(files_matching_query.hasNext()){

  // Get the file's Id
  var fileId = files_matching_query.next().getId();
}
```